# Partial Markdown parsing

Tags: ruby, markdown

I have an application that needs to parse a subset of Markdown. I basically only want to support inline elements (bold, italic, links, etc), not block level elements (p, h1, h2, etc).

There are a lot of different libraries, so I need some help narrowing it down (and a code sample would be helpful). I started using RedCarpet until I realized that I can't specify which elements I want to parse.

What Ruby Markdown library can I use to achieve this?

Comment: Would it be acceptable (easier) to parse a full Markdown and then use Nokogiri to post-process and remove or transform undesirable markup?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a library that allows you to specify on a granular level what parts of Markdown syntax are allowed. [RDiscount](http://rubydoc.info/github/rtomayko/rdiscount/master/RDiscount) has *some* configurability, however it doesn't take into account block level elements.

You could also give [Sanitize](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize/) a try (I know, parsing twice isn't exactly an ideal solution) and strip out the elements you don't want afterward.